# Live Objects: Error downloading json package in IDE Arduino

Tags: arduino-ide, orange-api

I am following the tutorial https://youtu.be/FP3iz2Hnv2k?list=PLlR5m9QWl2p_EPn3JITOF0pQsFuzOdle1  on how to manage the Orange explorer LoRa Kit.
And for choosing the type of card in Tools -> Card types, I get an error like: Error while downloading http://downloads.arduino.cc/packages/package_index.json

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly a problem of proxy with your box. There is nothing wrong with the packages link like that. Try to settle that and follow instructions again.

Answer (score 0):

For the Orange LoRa Explorer kit, you can use the infos from constructor Sodaq.
https://support.sodaq.com/Boards/ExpLoRer/

To add the card to Arduino IDE follow these steps :
- launch Arduino IDE
- go to preferences
- at "URL de préférence de cartes supplémentaires" you have an edit field and a button, click on it
- in the dialog box click on the text under the list or go to https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Unofficial-list-of-3rd-party-boards-support-urls
- search "SODAQ ExpLoRer", copy the linked url in the memo on Arduino IDE dialog box

Now you'll have the SODAQ Explorer card on card list.